# Python Selenium chrome settings

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm making program wih python, selenium and wanted to know how I can disable addressbar, toolbar, etc.

I'm using this code to open browser:

```
def resource_path(relative_path: str) -> str:
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

browser = webdriver.Chrome(resource_path('drivers/chromedriver'))
browser.get(link)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/56281705.html

In short, use chrome options class ( supported in python, Java and more ) and then choose the user capabilities to disable ( in link )